# Lalita hridaya with English meaning

Tags: resource, sri-vidya, lalita

I am looking for [lalita hridaya](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/shrIlalitAhRidayastotram.html?lang=sa) with English meaning. What is the importance of hridaya strotra.

Comment: The site developers may post the meaning in English shortly,  as per message available there. (https://stotram.co.in/lalita-hrudaya-stotram/)